# FireEvent / RaiseEvent / InvokeMember - what to use in .NET, and how?

Tags: vb.net, events, webbrowser-control, postback

I need to populate a number of dropdowns that each update the site.

Using VBScript I could use `IE.Document.GetElementById("Blahblah").FireEvent` - but this isn't working in VB.NET. So I have attempted to use `RaiseEvent` and `InvokeMember` instead, but neither seems to work in updating the form.

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="elements">
                    <select name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_PackageDropdown" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'_ctl0$MainContent$generateECodes_PackageDropdown\',\'\')', 0)" language="javascript" id="generateECodes_PackageDropdown">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">- Select a package -</option>
    <option value="272">McAfee Internet Security</option>
    <option value="273">3-User McAfee Internet Security</option>
    <option value="274">McAfee Total Protection</option>
    <option value="275">3-User McAfee Total Protection</option>
    <option value="379">McAfee Mobile Security - Smartphone Edition</option>
    <option value="381">McAfee Mobile Security - Tablet Edition</option>
    <option value="430">McAfee LiveSafe</option>

</select>
                    <select name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_TermDropdown" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'_ctl0$MainContent$generateECodes_TermDropdown\',\'\')', 0)" language="javascript" id="generateECodes_TermDropdown" disabled="disabled">
    <option selected="selected" value="- Select a term -">- Select a term -</option>

</select>
                    <select name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_Languages" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'_ctl0$MainContent$generateECodes_Languages\',\'\')', 0)" language="javascript" id="generateECodes_Languages" disabled="disabled">
    <option selected="selected" value="- Select a language -">- Select a language -</option>

</select>
                    <a id="generateECodes_VanityURL"></a>
                    <select name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_StoreNumber" id="generateECodes_StoreNumber" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
    <option value="0">- Select a store -</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1049 - Default Store</option>

</select>
                    <input name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_Required" type="text" maxlength="2" id="generateECodes_Required" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
```

So I am trying something like this to populate it:

```
Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_PackageDropdown")

        Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "430")
        Helem.RaiseEvent("onchange")

        Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_TermDropdown")

        If SA6.Checked Then
            Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "5")
        ElseIf SA12.Checked Then
            Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "1")
        ElseIf SA24.Checked Then
            Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "2")
        ElseIf SA36.Checked Then
            Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "3")
        End If
    End If
    Helem.RaiseEvent("onchange")

    Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Languages")

    Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "29")
    Helem.RaiseEvent("onchange")

    Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_StoreNumber")

    Helem.SetAttribute("Value", "230")
    Helem.RaiseEvent("onchange")

    Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Required")
    Helem.InnerText = "1"

    IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Button").Focus()
    Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Button")
    Helem.InvokeMember("click")
```

I have tried to change `RaiseEvent` with `InvokeMember`, and I have tried changing `onchange` to anything I could think of.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ended up getting it to work with: `Helem.InvokeMember("onchange")` - now im just having issues populating the `Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Required")` and then it seems the `Helem.InvokeMember("click")` for `IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Button")` isnt functioning properly either.. *sigh* VBScript was so much easier :P

Comment: If anyone can tell me why  `IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Button").Focus()
        Helem = IEMcAfee.Document.GetElementById("generateECodes_Button")
        Helem.InvokeMember("click")` isnt working for: `<input type="submit" name="_ctl0:MainContent:generateECodes_Button" value="Generate eCodes" id="generateECodes_Button" class="center">` i would be extremely happy.. Its breaking my head in, why it wont let me click.

Comment: And i have tryed with `InvokeMember("Click")` and `InvokeMember("submit")`